# Ayuda con un consecutivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql-workbench, phalcon

Buen día¡

Tengo un problema con una funcion.

Tego una tabla llamada def_cliente

```
| nombre | apellido| no_cart|
| ------ |---------| ------:|
| Globe  | Negro   | 98     |
| Scala  | Azul    | 489    |
| Palais | Granate | 66079  |
```

tengo una tabla llamada def_consecutivo

```
| rango  | desde   | hasta  |contador|
| ------ |---------| ------:|--------|
| z1     | 01      | 99     |21240   |
| z2     | 400     | 499    |492883  |
| z4     | 60000   | 69999  |35437   |
```

necesito que cuando se agregue un cliente se asigne a un rango y el contador de ese rango aumente.

me hace falta hacer la funcion que me realice el update del contador aumentando en uno tengo esto pero no me esta funcionando.

```
public function putAddConsecutiveClient($noCarteraSap)
{

    $sql ="SELECT iddef_consecutivo, rango_numeros, contador FROM def_consecutivo WHERE :no_cartera_sap  BETWEEN desde AND hasta";
    $modelConsecutivo =  $this->getResponseQueryOne($sql, ["no_cartera_sap"=>$noCarteraSap]);

    if (!empty($modelConsecutivo)) {
        return 'Error al relizar la actualizacion';
    }    
    $modelConsecutivo->contador = $modelConsecutivo->contador + 1; 
    if ($modelConsecutivo->save($modelConsecutivo)) {

        return $this->updateAction($modelConsecutivo);
    } else {
        return 'Error al agregar cliente';
    }

    return $this->getResponseQueryOne($sql,["contador"=>$modelConsecutivo]);
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar con esto que ya me esta poniendo loco.

Comment: Parece ser que lo que realmente tienes es un campo calculado, pero no queda claro del todo. ¿Puedes desarrollar un poco más en contexto y los requerimientos?

Comment: Claro. En la primera tabla tengo los clientes que cuentan con un numero de cartera que es el que establece a el rango en el que estaran. Cuando se agrega el cliente se asignara a un rango de la tabla def_consecutivo por ejemplo: si el numero de cartera es 10 se asignara al rango z1. Una vez que se este asignado a el rango que le corresponde se debe aumentar el contador de dicho rango en este caso el contador de z1 esta en 21240 y aumentaría a 21241. Espero haberme explicado un poco mejor. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Tienes algún error? Alguna excepción en tu código? Esta línea me causa dudas `if (!empty($modelConsecutivo))` quiere decir que si encuentra un registro luego del select te muestre el mensaje indicado y salga de la función lo que en la práctica finaliza la ejecución de la función y nunca actualizará contador.

Comment: No, mas bien quiere decir ahi que si la variable esta vacia o nula mande el mensaje o eso es lo que pretendo hacer en esa parte.